# Is there a short way to instantiate a class with the constructor params?

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, method-parameters

I am using python 3.4

```
class baba():
  def __init__(self,a,b,c,d,e,f,g):
     self.a = a
     self.b = b
     self.c = c
     self.d = d
     self.e = e
     self.f = f
     self.g = g
```

IS there a shorter way to write this? **Beside getting all of those as a dict**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `**kwargs`, then use `setattr` to create your instance attributes:

```
class baba():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for i in kwargs:
            setattr(self, i, kwargs[i])

b = baba(a=1,b=2,c=4,d=5)
print(b.a) # prints 1
```